# Get week of UK fiscal year

Tags: python

I want to get the week number corresponding to the UK fiscal year (which runs 6th April to 5th April). `report_date.strftime('%V')` will give me the week number corresponding to the calendar year (1st January to 31st December).

For example, today is 2nd February which is UK fiscal week `44`, but `%V` would return `05`.

I've seen the https://pypi.org/project/fiscalyear/ library but it doesn't seem to offer a way to do this. I know that I can work out the number of days since April 6th and divide by 7, but just curious if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job in Python. It counts the number of days since April 6th of the given year (`formatted_report_date`), and if the answer is negative (because April 6th hasn't passed yet), then a year is subtracted. Then divide by 7 and add 1 (for 1-indexing). The answer will be between 1-53.

```py
def get_fiscal_week(formatted_report_date):
    """
    Given a date, returns the week number (from 1-53) since the last April 6th.

    :param formatted_report_date: the formatted date to be converted into a
                                  fiscal week.
    """

    from datetime import datetime
    fiscal_start = formatted_report_date.replace(month=4, day=6)
    days_since_fiscal_start = (formatted_report_date - fiscal_start).days
    if days_since_fiscal_start < 0:
        fiscal_start = fiscal_start.replace(year=fiscal_start.year-1)
        days_since_fiscal_start = (formatted_report_date - fiscal_start).days

    return (days_since_fiscal_start / 7) + 1
```